# I cannot find what is wrong with this C program to check whether a number is prime or not using function

Tags: c

I know this may be a dumb question, but I cannot find what is wrong with this code. Here I have initialized a function which checks whether the number entered is prime or not.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int check_prime(int n)
{
    int i,count=0;
    for(i=2;i<n/2;i++)
     {
         if(n%i==0)
          {
              count++;
          }
     }
     if(count==0)
      {
          printf("the number is prime");
      }
    
}
int main()
{
    int n;
    printf("enter the number,\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int check_prime(int n);
    return 0;
}
```

the output only shows:

```
enter the number
```

after I enter the number it does not display anything.

Comment: You missed else condition. Write a `printf` statememt for not prime.

Comment: `check_prime` returns nothing, so its return type should be `void`, not `int`.

Comment: Please extract a [mcve] and provide that first. As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 3):

```
int check_prime(int n);
```

Is not a call of function but a declaration of function.

It should be

```
check_prime(n);
```

to call the function.

Answer (score 2):

The answer above is perfect. Since you said you are new to the programming world, I'd love to explain a bit more.

#### Philosophical Answer:

- In C/C++, when you *declare the function*, you tell the compiler, "Hey, I have created a function foo(), watch out".
- And when you *call the function*, you tell the compiler, "Yo, do you remember that thing I told you to watch out for? I need to access it now".

#### Technical Answer:

- Syntactically, `int check_prime(int n);` is how you *declare a function*.
- And `check_prime(n); //n is an integer` is how you *call the function*.

Comment: and then, scope comes into play. since you might ask, why does the compiler allow me to declare a function twice?

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be 3 problems.

**The return type of `check_prime`**

You declare `int check_prime(int n)`, which means the function should return an `int`. In this case, your function never returns anything, it just prints stuff, so a return type of `void` is more suitable.

**You declare `check_prime` again in `main` instead of calling it**

In `main`, when you say `int check_prime(int n);` you are actually declaring a `check_prime` function again, not calling it. You would call it as `check_prime(n);`.

**The algorithm has a bug in it**

As it is, your algorithm thinks `4` is a prime number (which it is not).

In your `for` loop, you check if `n` is divisible by the integers from `2` to `(n / 2) - 1`, because the termination condition is `i < n/2`, which is true when `i == n / 2`. For the example of `4`, this mean it never runs the `for` loop.

The termination condition in the loop should be changed to `i <= n / 2`, as in:

```
for(i = 2; i <= n / 2; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

> after I enter the number it does not display anything

Aside from the non-call to `check_prime()` should be replaced with a call

```
// int check_prime(int n);  // This is only a function declaration.
check_prime(n);
```

Prime detection is very slow for large values and can be significantly sped up.

```
//for(i=2;i<n/2;i++) {
//  if(n%i==0) {
//    count++;
//  }
//}

//         vvvv 
for(i=2; i<=n/i; i++) {
  if(n%i==0) {
    count++;
    break; // add
  }
}
```